# Why aren't persistent connections supported by URLLib2?

Tags: python, urllib2, keep-alive

After scanning the `urllib2` source, it seems that connections are automatically closed even if you do specify keep-alive.

Why is this?

As it is now I just use `httplib` for my persistent connections... but wonder why this is disabled (or maybe just ambiguous) in urllib2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a well-known limit of urllib2 (and urllib as well).  IMHO the best attempt so far to fix it and make it right is Garry Bodsworth's [coda_network](http://blog.programmerslog.com/?p=423) for Python 2.6 or 2.7 -- replacement, patched versions of urllib2 (and some other modules) to support keep-alive (and a bunch of other smaller but *quite* welcome fixes).

Comment: Alex, finally a straight answer on this one ('its' a well known limit'), The question remains though, why is URLLib2 written this way?

Comment: @sbartell, because nobody felt the problem was important enough to submit a patch to the Python code and have it accepted -- I didn't, neither did you, and so on for millions of people who could and no doubt would **if** they felt the problem was important (assuming they're decent citizens of the open-source community, of course, but, hey, aren't we all?-).  I think Gary took the right approach by releasing a third-party solution so that lots of real-world "field" experience in a variety of uses can be accumulated before things are "frozen" into the standard library.

Answer (score 3):

You might also check out [httplib2](https://github.com/httplib2/httplib2), which supports persistent connections. Not quite the same as urllib2 (in the sense that it only does http and not "any kind of url"), but easier than httplib (and imho also easier than urllib2 if you really want to do http).

Comment: httplib does support them, we just use the same httpconnection object over again.

Comment: It just boggles me why urllib2 does support this.